How to use spl_token account with solana-program-test crate?
I am trying to write a test with the solana-program-test crate for a solana program. This program makes a CPI to a token program:
let ix = Instruction {
            program_id: *token_program.key,
            accounts,
            data,
        };

        invoke_signed(
            &ix,
            &[source, destination, authority, token_program],
            signers,
        )

The actual problem is that I am configuring the necessary data in test and I do not know if I am configuring the parameters of the token account properly, and the output fails with this information:
[2024-05-19T13:16:32.214732000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Source: AccountInfo { key: C4hnLciKTRbQBpVudEUNUspTVzji7hjbXQto8HWHmFs2, owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, is_signer: false, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 0, lamports: 100000, data.len: 165, data: 0000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f7264700bf2f678de6636c426bf6e31f19c5ab95734ec388bbc3b297ed925332, .. }
[2024-05-19T13:16:32.214761000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Destination: AccountInfo { key: 9QWRBvbNqmTogWomnRB1ikC4Ygsz2vquP63bAVpczRCp, owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, is_signer: false, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 0, lamports: 100000, data.len: 165, data: 00000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006d1fb1f1c3190167c15dee881fdabbb5001eeb801d42f35ed14baa65d4f8a02f, .. }
[2024-05-19T13:16:32.214782000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Authority: AccountInfo { key: HdmZ8mg7K7Ppwds7utZ5zWzgYFEoeMtSWM7HvSnUzuny, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: true, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 0, lamports: 100000, data.len: 0, .. }
[2024-05-19T13:16:32.214805000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Token program: AccountInfo { key: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, is_signer: false, is_writable: false, executable: true, rent_epoch: 0, lamports: 100000, data.len: 0, .. }
[2024-05-19T13:16:32.214814000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]
test test::test_transaction ... FAILED

successes:

successes:

failures:

---- test::test_transaction stdout ----
thread 'solBankForksCli' panicked at /Users/srivas/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-test-1.16.23/src/lib.rs:312:77:
Unsupported program id

The configuration in the test is the following:
 // Token program id account initialization
        let token_program_id_key = spl_token::id();
        let token_program_id_account_data_size = 0;
        let token_program_id_account_lamports = 100000;
        let mut token_program_id_account = Account::new(token_program_id_account_lamports, 
     token_program_id_account_data_size, &spl_token::id());
        token_program_id_account.executable = true;

   program_test.add_account(token_program_id_key, token_program_id_account);

Please, feel free to ask me any information. I tried to explain the problem the best way possible.
Thanks in advance.

By providing an account with no data as the SPL Token program, your test is actually replacing the SPL Token program with an unusable program. This is an error condition, since the runtime does not normally allow deploying an invalid program.
The SPL Token program is provided by default in solana-program-test, so you can safely eliminate your code to add the account.
There's a larger example doing exactly what you want at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/examples/rust/transfer-tokens
